# Display a disabled 'comment' link when not entitles to comment

Tags: feature-request

I recently hit an issue where I incorrectly suggested an edit to a solution but really I just wanted to comment on the solution. I didn't have enough rep to be able to comment_everywhere so the comment link didn't appear and the only thing available to me was to suggest an edit.

This is wrong and is going to bit new users the most.

I think it would be better to display a disabled comment link with a tooltip like:

"You need 50 reputation to be able to comment on other peoples posts. Consider suggesting an alternative answer."

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't have enough rep to be able to comment_everywhere so the comment link didn't appear and the only thing available to me was to suggest an edit.

Suggesting a **wrong** edit just to comment is always bad. No matter the reason. If the suggested edit is valid to change something that needed to be changed in the post and made it through the review process, congratulation you did what you had to do.

> I think it would be better to display a disabled comment link with a tooltip like:
>
> "You need 50 reputation to be able to comment on other peoples posts. Consider suggesting an alternative answer."

I don't think this should be implemented. We cannot simply start by showing all possible options on the interface and grey them out when you don't have access to them. Next time you will edit when you need to Flag or Close and ask for these options to be added even though you can't use them ? This is, *imho*, bad design.

If new users take the time to read the [Faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) or the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) or any documentation that should be read before posting they won't have any problems like this.

**50 rep is nothing**. You can earn that easily in a day by giving 1 or 2 good answers. But you did the right thing by asking this here. Don't give up you'll be able to comment in no time.

Comment: I agree that in general there's a case to be made for hiding unavailable UI, but I feel like commenting is a special case. As a new user it seems like the first step to interacting with the community and getting involved in topics that you don't necessarily have a question or answer for, just some information. Everyone is familiar with commenting on everything from YouTube to Facebook, and while I agree SE is different (and rightly so) the details of the commenting rights is relatively buried in the documentation considering what a workflow it is, and one that new users can easily relate to

Comment: @steeveeet Good point. It is one of the first step indeed (after readin the doc Imo). **But** , I'm strickly talking about your request  to show a greyed out comment here button for new user which would be futile because it would not let you interteract more with the community and would just be bad design. Once again in my opinion. Your comment looks more like an argument on the *should new users be able to comment before 50 rep*. I don't disagree with you I event think new users should be able to comment.